# In a Bash script, not able to use while and for loop together. Getting unexpected end of file error

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9
for i in 8.00 7.50 7.00 6.50 6.00 5.50 5.00 ;
do
echo '6.0' $i $col6 >> 1.dat 
done < "sih1.66"
```

getting error - syntax error: unexpected end of file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `while` and `for` need their own set of `do` and `done` to surround the loop bodies. So you probably want this:

```
while read -r col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9; do 
    for i in 8.00 7.50 7.00 6.50 6.00 5.50 5.00; do
        echo '6.0' "$i" "$col6" 
    done
done < "sih1.66" >> 1.dat
```

If everything inside the loop is redirected to the same place, you can put the output redirection outside the loop too. It might make the redirection a bit more visible and might be ever so slightly faster, but either one works.

---

But why does it say "unexpected end of file", and not just plain "syntax error", when you used `for` in place of the expected `do`?

That's because the `while` loop condition part can also take multiple commands, and a `for` loop can be one of them. Sounds a bit weird though, not nearly all programming languages allow something like that. But the shell does.

So, the below version would be valid too, and it'd work somewhat alike the above... just that it'd use the return value *of the `for`-loop* as the `while` loop condition. That's probably not what you want, since the the `read` failing wouldn't make the loop stop.

```
while read -r col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9;
      for i in 8.00 7.50 7.00 6.50 6.00 5.50 5.00; do
          echo '6.0' "$i" "$col6" 
      done; do 
      true # need to have some command here
done
```

As an aside, since you're on Bash, you could use an array instead of separate numbered variables:

```
while read -r -a cols; do 
    for i in 8.00 7.50 7.00 6.50 6.00 5.50 5.00; do
        echo '6.0' "$i" "${cols[5]}" 
    done
done < "sih1.66" >> 1.dat
```

Just note that the array indexing starts from zero in Bash.